# Python multiple events in a channel

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a bot to delete any new messages typed in the channel and at the same time, if anyone types "ok" then he/she will be given a role. It's running fine but I received a trackback for `await message.delete()` in my other channel right after I put the same in the first channel.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 809051707996110858:
        await message.delete()  ***<--- (A)***
    if message.content.lower() == 'ok':
        member = message.author
        KING = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=794268294173294612)
        await member.add_roles(KING, atomic=True)

    if message.channel.id == 856111860931887104:
         message.content=message.content.lower()
         if  message.content in codeword:
            await message.delete() ***#traceback occurs here when I put (A)***
```

Comment: Can you share the error message you get and the libraries you are using ?

Comment: I do not know what libraries I'm using, I learned it from youtube videos on how to create a discord bot.

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AORUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Program Files\Git\bot.py", line 42, in on_message
    await message.delete()

Comment: File "C:\Users\AORUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 1023, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_message(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "C:\Users\AORUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message